# C# Threading - All threads are calculating same random value , why is that?

Tags: c#, multithreading, random

program is asking 10 threads and launching it on a function which is printing random value , but all those threads are printing the same Random value .

My friends says that it is due to thread are using rand calculation at same CPU clock so that is why. Is he right

And if there is a solution for it ?

```
      private DateTime randomNum()
    {

         Random r = new Random();
        int rInt = r.Next();
    }
```

button_click1

```
         for (int i = 0; i < numofThreads; i++)
        {

            res[i] = delcall.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }
        //int[] num = new int[numofThreads];
        for (int i = 0; i < numofThreads; i++) {
            DateTime dt = delcall.EndInvoke(res[i]);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(dt + "\n ");
        }
```

Comment: This has been asked heaps of times, you need to put `private Random r = new Random();` outside the function, declaring it each time will make non-random. I'l l find the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new instance of `Random` every time. If multiple `Random` instances are created at the same time, their seed is the same. This means they all behave equal. Just use one `Random` instance multiple times. Therefore declare it outside of the method.

```
private readonly Random r = new Random();
private DateTime randomNum()
{   
    int rInt = r.Next();
}
```